# Flutter arabic showDatePicker Morocco localization

Tags: flutter, datepicker, localization

I want to make a flutter date picker with the Arabic language but with some changes, this is my code :

```
  locale: Locale('ar', 'MA'),
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('ar', 'MA'),
  ],
```

result :
[image]

What I want is this (changes in red color) :

[image]

Please any help.

Comment: Do I understand that you want to change the format of displayed month and selected date? Could you perhaps write what should be this format? `YYYY mm`?

Comment: I want to change the name of month essentially and the numbers format.

Comment: I have some idea with providing custom MaterialLocalizationsDelegate derived class that overrides `formatDateTime()` method. I'm gonna check if it works and let you know.

Comment: I dont know if we can override DateSymbols class to change the elements : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/date_symbols/DateSymbols-class.html . any idea ?

Comment: My idea is to overwrite MaterialLocalizations delegate's formatDateTime methods for part of subtree where you want to use showDateTimePIcker. When the picker is built it uses these methods to format months and other dates

Comment: No some lines of code ? I think I wil switch to Cupertino Date picker, what do you think about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for my post :
in my splash screen I override the DateSymbols values as desired like this :

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
DateFormat arLangue = new DateFormat('', 'ar');
arLangue.dateSymbols.MONTHS = myDateSymboles.MONTHS;
arLangue.dateSymbols.FIRSTDAYOFWEEK = 7;
arLangue.dateSymbols.ZERODIGIT = "0";}
```

Thanks lot

Comment: i have the same problem can you give me the full code